# global variable gives "undefined" in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I have to functions that execute when two different `<img>` are clicked on. I have to communicate a variable between them.

Getting rid of the irrelevant code, what I have looks something like this:

```
var size=0;

    $('#gallery img').click(function(){

        window.size = $('#lightbox img').attr('data-size');

    });


    $('#lightbox i').click(function(){

                var dest=window.size-1;
    });
```

But, when I go to the javascript console, and type `size`, I get `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace**

```
window.size
```

**With**

```
size
```

because its javascript custom variable not a window object property

**EDIT**

```
var size=0;

$('#gallery img').click(function()
{
    size = $('#lightbox img').attr('data-size');
});

$('#lightbox i').click(function()
{
    var dest = size-1;
    alert(dest);
    alert(size);
});
```

above code will alert `0` and `-1` if you first click on `#ligtbox i` now if you first click on `#gallery img` then it will alert result depending on `click` you made.

Comment: I still get `undefined`.

Comment: *"custom variable not a window object property"* If it is a global variable, it is a property of `window`.

Answer (score 1):

**Change**

```
window.size
```

**to**

```
size
```

and `$('#lightbox img').attr('data-size');`

to

`$('#lightbox img').data('size');`